# Web app for drawing base64 image code (CSS)

Tags: web-apps, images, css, image-editor, image

There's a web app I used to use that enables one to use their cursor to draw into a something-by-something pixel grid (user-specified), and that would be output as a base64 CSS background image in code. (I forgot if it was PNG or GIF...)

Now I'm searching the web, but can't find it. Does anyone know this web app that I'm talking about? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find the web app! It's a site called **patternify.com**

Seems it must've gotten buried in search rankings over time, as the site has not upgraded to **https** at the time of this writing. Too bad, cuz it's quite handy for making things like [this background](https://codepen.io/blendamental/pen/bJWGyO).